# QPushButton and clicked slot

Tags: c++, qt5

i have a `verticalLayout` that there's three labels with a button in each line. when i click on each button the event

```
button_clicked()
{

}
```

is firing. this event is for all button i.e when i click on each of button this function is called. now i want when i click on each button the same row that button is in that remove. how can i do that? first of all must be a unique value that i detect which button is clicked and second i must delete that row but i know how.
any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-answering, with the additional data provided at the comment:

You can connect all buttons to the same slot and then use the `sender()` method to identify who is triggering the signal:

```
void MyClass::button_clicked() {
    QAbstractButton* button = qobject_cast<QAbstractButton*>(sender());
    if ( !button ) {
        return; // not called from a button.
    }
    button->setText("Clicked");
}
```

Comment: Gobbo A. de Oli accurate that buttons number aren't fix and they add run time.may be they was 1200 so i must add 1200 fuction.

Comment: Just re-answered it, with a more suitable method in both occasions.